# Does Google Search Appliance care about files permissions?

Tags: file-permissions, cifs, google-search-appliance

My file server has different files visible to different people, based on groups and file permissions.

I planned to buy a **Google Search Appliance** and configure it to crawl this network shared drive via [CIFS](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Server_Message_Block) (aka SMB).

Will the **search appliance** present a user **only** with files to which he/she has access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Google documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/60/secure_search/secure_search_crwlsrv.html):

> When a user performs a search request,
>   the search appliance performs these
>   checks before serving secure content:
>
> 1. If you specify policy ACLs (access control list) rules, the
>      search appliance checks to see if a
>      policy ACL rules applies to a target
>      document. If a rule applies to a URL
>      pattern, then the search appliance
>      grants or denies access to the URL
>      based on the rule. If a rule does not
>      apply then the search appliance
>      continues to Step 2.
> 2. The search appliance acquires the user's credentials to enable
>      impersonation, or performs an
>      authentication check to establish the
>      user's identity. If Kerberos
>      authentication is specified under
>      Crawler Access, the search appliance
>      will try Kerberos authentication
>      before attempting other methods.
> 3. The search appliance impersonates the user, or performs an
>      authorization check to determine
>      whether the user can view the content.
>      If the user is authorized to view the
>      content, the content will appear in
>      the user's search results.

So you can set it up to only show the user files they have permission to use.